# Cannot find function which return array of weekly date relative from today dynamically

Tags: php, date, datetime, php-carbon

as the title said, I've been googling it but got no clue.

here's the thing, let's say I have a function which takes an integer parameter. when I invoke it i.e `scoutWeekly(1)`, it lists first week of this month (28 Jan-03 Feb). If I give the parameter `2` of the function, it lists the second week of this month (04 Feb-10 Feb). so on... it all should be relative to this day e.g if it's invoked`scoutWeekly(1)`, it jumps to (28 Jan-03 Feb)

Do you guys have any clue or snippet?

Comment: Hint: get the weekday of the first of the month (that should be pretty simple), see what its value is and do some simple math adding/subtracting a few days.

Comment: it's 01-02 February if it's looked upon this month, right?

Comment: Depends how you define “first week”. Typically it’s the *entire week* Mon-Sun (or Sun-Sat, depending where you live) that’s more than half in this month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function weeks($month, $year)
{
    $num_of_days = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
    $lastday     = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
    $no_of_weeks = 0;
    $count_weeks = 0;
    while ($no_of_weeks < $lastday)
    {
        $no_of_weeks += 7;
        $count_weeks++;
    }
    return $count_weeks;
}

function getRangeByWeek($weekNo)
{
    $firstDayOfCurrentMonth = date('Y-m-01');
    $globalWeek             = intval(date('W', strtotime($firstDayOfCurrentMonth)));
    $globalYear             = intval(date('Y', strtotime($firstDayOfCurrentMonth)));
    $globalMonth            = intval(date('m', strtotime($firstDayOfCurrentMonth)));
    $totalNumberOfWeeks     = weeks($globalMonth, $globalYear);
    $date                   = new DateTime();
    $result                 = [];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalNumberOfWeeks; $i++)
    {
        $startDate  = $date->setISODate($globalYear, $globalWeek)->format("d M");
        $endDate    = $date->setISODate($globalYear, $globalWeek, 7)->format("d M");
        $result[$i] = $startDate . '-' . $endDate;
        $globalWeek++;
    }
    return $result[$weekNo];
}
echo getRangeByWeek(1);
```

1. Extracted Global Week from the first day of the current month and required Year and month
2. Took total weeks in the current month
3. Created empty DateTime instance to perform easy calculation and get the first date of the global week
4. Incremented Global weeks upto the total number of weeks in the current month
5. whatever result generated I kept index as week number of the current month
6. returned date range of current week number from current month

**Output**

```
28 Jan-03 Feb
```

[**Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3d87118a877057830edd92b014ad722531c37a76)

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way...

```
function scoutWeekly($n) {
    // today's date
    $today = new DateTime();
    // set to first day of the month
    $today->setDate($today->format('Y'), $today->format('m'), 1);
    // get the Monday earlier
    $today->sub(new DateInterval('P' . ($today->format('N') - 1) . 'D'));
    // add the required number of weeks
    if ($n > 1) {
        $today->add(new DateInterval('P' . ($n - 1) . 'W'));
    }
    // and format the result
    return $today->format('d M') . '-' . $today->add(new DateInterval('P6D'))->format('d M');
}
echo scoutWeekly(1)
```

Output:

```
28 Jan-03 Feb
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kAIol)

Answer (score 0):

I'm the OP

this is the solved answer:

```php
    private static function addScoutWeek(int $addNumb = null) : array
    {
        $addStart = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addWeek($addNumb)->startOfWeek();
        $interval = new \DateInterval('P1D');
        $addEnd = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addWeek($addNumb)->endOfWeek();
        $dateRange = new \DatePeriod($addStart, $interval, $addEnd);

        foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
            $arrOfDate[] = $date;
        }

        return $arrOfDate;
    }
```

case closed